# Content type export broken in PHP 5.4

Tags: nodes, entities, importing-exporting, 6

I am trying to upgrade my server from PHP 5.3 to 5.4. When accessing the Content Type export form in CCK with D6 the form does not display.

This issue is on first display of the form, not just on submit (as I have seen other questions online).

Here is the bad form.

[image: Bad Form]

Here is the correct form (on PHP 5.3).

[image: Good Form]

I don't have any errors being thrown to the error_log or watchdog, and I am using Pressflow 6.26.

Comment: Are you sure you have error reporting set to `E_ALL` ?

Comment: yes, I've set reporting to E_ALL without any errors being reported

Answer (score 1):

Line 623 of modules/cck/modules/content_copy/content_copy.module needs to be changed from:

```
function template_preprocess_content_copy_export_form($vars) {
```

to

```
function template_preprocess_content_copy_export_form(&$vars) {
```

https://drupal.org/node/2230081